Confusion about reference point for potential difference
My confusion comes from trying to find the potential difference of a spherical conductor with an inner shell of radius $R_1$ and an outer radius $R_2$.
I tried using a reference point of $R_1$ and used the negative integral of $\mathbf{E}$ to find:
$$\phi(r) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{R_1}\right) & R_1 < r < R_2 \\
\dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\dfrac{1}{R_2}-\dfrac{1}{R_1}\right) & r > R_2 \end{cases}$$
So the potential difference between the spheres is then
$$\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{1}{R_1}\right)$$
but I know it should be
$$\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right).$$
Where am I going wrong? I think I have a major conceptual misunderstanding.

Basic tutorial on how to write mathematical equations on this site:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Your equations are written in a very sloppy way, so most likely they just contain some error.

What’s the polarity of the charges on the two surfaces?

You most likely integrated incorrectly. $R_1$ is at a higher potential than $R_2$

$\dots$ I know it should be $\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\cdot \left( \frac {1}{R_1}- \frac {1}{R_2}\right)$ is an incorrect statement and your integration gave you the correct answer.
Since you are finding the potential difference between the two spheres all you need to consider is the charge $Q$ on the inner sphere and the potential difference with $R_1$ as the reference is $\dfrac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\cdot \dfrac {1}{R_2}- \dfrac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\cdot \dfrac {1}{R_1}$.
Check
$Q$ positive, the potential is decreasing as one moves away from the inner sphere, ie, the potential difference is negative as $Q/R_1>Q/R_2$.
$Q$ negative, the potential is increasing as one moves away from the inner sphere, ie, the potential difference is positive as $Q/R_1<Q/R_2$.

You must note that potential inside a uniformly charged spherical shell is constant.
This will be your main concept in dealing with Potential Difference between two spherical shells.
(assuming that both spherical shells are charged Q).
Potential at surface of sphere A,

Potential at surface of sphere B,

Hence potential difference between the two spherical shells will be:

Let me tell you that there is no need to integrate to find the potential difference for this case.


Please use MathJax and not images.

Alright I didn't know about MathJax.
